# Is it normal that GNU Octave plot has issues with the background when plotting?

Tags: plot, background, octave, fedora

Every time I try to plot a function using GNU Octave, I have issues with the background. For instance, see the images at the end of this question. First, I opened a black window, then "plot" command was executed in the shell, giving "1_black.png" as the result. Second, a pdf file mostly white was opened and the same command was executed in the shell, as before. "1_white.png" shows what happened. In both of these cases it is the grid that doesn't look as it should, but sometimes even the curves are not properly shown in the plot. Does anyone have this same issue?
Relevant system info:

- Fedora 33 workstation Ed. (It also happened with previous Fedora versions).
- 64-bit
- GNOME version 3.38.2
- Graphics NVD9

I'll appreciate any guidance on this!

Additional info:

- The exact code to reproduce it is the following:

  plot(1:10) , grid minor
- Both images were saved by doing screenshots. Although these may not be strictly identical to the screen output, the problem is seen even before saving them.
- Output of "graphics_toolkit()":

  octave:3> graphics_toolkit()
  ans = qt
- Output of: ver Octave

  ```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
    GNU Octave Version: 5.2.0 (hg id: eb46a9f47164)
    GNU Octave License: GNU General Public License
    Operating System: Linux 5.9.11-200.fc33.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 24 18:18:01 UTC 2020 x86_64}
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```

[image: Black]

[image: White]

Comment: can you edit your question to type the exact code that produced these (including what you did to save them), so that we can try for ourselves? also, what is the output of the command `graphics_toolkit()` in the octave terminal? Also, which octave version do you have? (you can find out by typing `ver Octave` in the octave terminal)

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, @TasosPapastylianou
I just edited the question.

Comment: I just noticed that using a different graphics toolkit, e.g. gnuplot, the problem does not arise anymore, so I'm guessing "qt" has the issue here. When switching to "gnuplot", the command "grid" performs as expected, but "grid minor" does not add a minor grid. Don't Octave's standard commands work with "gnuplot"?

Comment: There's a few confusing things happening here. First of all, the graph you get is not the default graph one would expect; the linewidth's are fat, both for the axes and the plot object involved. E.g. to reproduce your graph I need to do `h1 = axes; plot( 1 : 10, 'linewidth', 2 ); grid minor; set( gca, 'linewidth', 2 );`, rather than just `plot(1:10)`. Secondly, I don't get what you mean by "open black first and white second", but clearly that's not equivalent to a simple `plot(1:10)`, so I'm not sure if you've reproduced the procedure correctly for me to try to reproduce locally.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the 'root' graphical object by any chance?

Comment: You're right, my bad. I added in ~/.octaverc the following lines:
set(0,'defaultlinelinewidth',3), set(0,'defaultaxeslinewidth',3), set(0,'defaultaxesfontsize',14), set(0,'defaultaxesfontweight','bold')

Specifically, by "black window" I meant opening and maximizing an emacs window with black color. Then I went to the shell (alt+tab) and typed the command. By "white window" I did the same, but instead of emacs I opened a .pdf file, with a mostly white color, so behind the plot there was a white color. The result is that the way the plot looks like is influenced by what's behind it.

Comment: I just tried "fltk" graphics toolkit and it works perfectly fine. I suppose there's something wrong with "Qt" in my PC.

Comment: Maybe? In any case, to me this sounds suspiciously like a compositing issue, unrelated to octave. Perhaps something to do with emacs? In any case, it's unusual for octave plot _windows_ to display transparency. I don't know why 'qt' would produce transparency of the _window_ like this, but it's certainly not intended behaviour.